# Learning Node.js..'require' not working. Is it no longer used in newest nod.js version

Tags: node.js

New to node.js.  While i was trying to create var http = require('http') for creating server it does not allow in VS code

Want to know if 'require' is no longer used in newer version of node js

Below suggestion keeps popping up...why is not letting me use require

File is a CommonJS module; it may be converted to an ES module.ts(80001)
var require: NodeRequire
(id: string) => any

```
const port=8080;
var msg="Hello World";
console.log(msg);
import { createServer } from "http";
//var http = require("http");  Not allowing to create http instead asking to import createServer
//http.createServer(function(req,res){res.end('Hello World!'); }).listen(8080);

const server = createServer(function(req,res){res.end('Hello World!'); });


server.port(port,function(error){

    if(error){
        console.log("Something went wrong");
    } else{
        console.log("server running on port "+port)
    }
})
```

Comment: "It does not allow"? What does not allow? It's a suggestion that says you _could_ use ES modules, but you don't need to.

Comment: if you rename your file extension from `js` to `cjs` then node should see it as CommonJS and not complain anymore (depends what setup you have, of course).

Comment: It looks like a suggestion in vscode

Comment: Well its working now...weirdly it was throwing error earlier. May be something with vscode.